# What is the use of an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know that abstract base classes are those which have a pure virtual function and objects of abstract base class cannot be created.

So , why should we create a class which cannot define its object?

Comment: I can't see what's that bad with this question, that it should deserve so many downvotes? It's basic, but not too broad, or unclear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a contract of sorts used between developers to say "This is the type of functionality we want to implement", and leaves the implementation up to the developers if the classes they want to design are to inherit the base class.

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Animal
{
    public:
        Animal() {}
        virtual void sound() = 0;
};

/* Dog class is derived from base class Animal */
class Dog : public Animal   
{
    public:
        Dog() {}
        void sound() 
        {
            cout << "woof!" << endl;
        }
};
```

Here, `Dog` is an `Animal`, and must implement it's own sound. The base class `Animal`'s sound() function implies that Animals make sounds, and that any class that inherits from `Animal` should implement a sound function. From this, you could make a `Cat` class that outputs a meow from its sound class, as well as a `Bear` class that outputs a roar, etc.

Comment: That's not an abstract base class; it's just a weird way to (ab)use inheritance to bolt functions onto an existing class.

Comment: Area "is a" Rectangle...hmmmm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I changed it to be something a little more understandable.

Comment: Still not abstract, nor even polymorphic. The function should be pure virtual in the base class, to make it abstract.

Comment: Fixed again. It's been a long weekend.....

Answer (score 2):

We want them to provide interface descriptions, and force deriving classes to implement these interfaces.

```
 struct IRender;
 struct IShape {
      virtual void Draw(IRender& render) = 0;
      virtual ~IShape() {}
 };

 struct IRender {
      virtual void RenderShape(IShape& shape) = 0;
      virtual ~IRender() {}
 };
```

At this point we don't want to know about the concrete implementations.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a pure virtual class which serves as an interface, you can also have a class with a combination of pure virtual functions and functions with definitions. This is useful for a polymorphic base class which needs defined behavior from the subclasses but can't implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a basic inheritance example:

```
class Animal { virtual void Eat() = 0; };// pure virtual base class
class Dog : Animal { ... };// tangible, real class
```

Implementing Dog::Eat is straight-forward. But how would you implement "Animal::Eat"? There is no generic implementation of "Eat"; you need a specific type of animal to know how to implement such an action.

Answer (score 1):

A abstract class doesn't have any object but it can have a pointer which can hold address of derived class object.using this we can perform operations on derived classes

```
class Base {    
    public:
      virtual void method1();
}

class Derived:public Base {
// 1. List item

  void method1() {
     cout<<"in derived 1"<<endl;
  }
}

int main() {
    Base *ptr;
    Derived d;

    ptr=&d;
    ptr->method1();

}
```

Comment: You can can create an instance of Base though once you define the body of method1. By definition you cannot instantiate abstract base classes.